# No se inserta ruta de imagen a tabla de mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7, fileupload

Tengo el siguiente programa php para insertar imágenes a una base de datos a mysql y a la carpeta del servidor, las inserciones tanto a la carpeta y a la tabla se hacen correctamente. La estructura de mi tabla es la siguiente:

```
id   |   idRegistro   |    foto1   |   foto2    |   foto3    |    ruta   |
```

Donde los campos foto1, 2, y 3 son de tipo LONGBLOB y son insertados sin problema y idRegistro es llave foranea, mientras que ruta es varchar y tengo intenciones de guardar la ruta para poderla consultar después en PHP pero **LA RUTA NO SE INSERTA**

El php que utilizo para estos procesos es el siguiente:

```
 <?php
 include("conexion.php");
 $id_registro = $_POST['id_registro'];
 //aqui van las imagenes (Carpeta o ruta que usaras)
 $path = "imagenes/";
 //$directorio = opendir("$path");

 //Hacemos un poco de código verificando que se recibieron las imagenes
 if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){

//almacenamos las propiedades de las imagenes
$name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
$tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
$type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
$size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
$error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];

//recorremos el array de imagenes para subirlas al simultaneo
for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i],  "imagenes/".$name_array[$i])){

        //guardamos en la base de datos el nombre
        $act = "INSERT INTO imagenes_registros (id_registro,foto1,foto2,foto3,ruta) 
values ('$id_registro','$name_array[0]','$name_array[1]','$name_array[2]', '$tmp_name_array')";
        if($mysqli->query($act)){
          echo "<img src='".$path.$name_array[$i]."'> Las imágenes fueron subidas exitosamente.<br>";

    }
    else
    {
        //si ocurrio algun problema entonces
        echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
    }
}
}}
```

PD: Inserto 3 imágenes al mismo tiempo.

bar_dump:
[image: contenido al usar]

Comment: Es bueno que digas exactamente lo que ocurre, no solo, *la ruta no se inserta*, sino decir si da error, si imprime algún mensaje del código, etc. Lo primero que hay que verificar es tu consulta, puedes hacer un `echo $act;`  y decirnos lo que imprime. Y puedes también intentar mostrar el error, si es que lo hubiera con: **`echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for {$name_array[$i]} El error es: {$mysqli->error}<br>";`**

Comment: @A. Cedano , Gracias por la observación. El error que me regresa es "Notice: Array to string conversion in" la linea de la consulta y literalmente inserta la palabra "Array" en la Base de Datos.

Comment: ¿Podrías por favor mostrar un `var_dump($_FILES['file_array']);` para ver lo que hay dentro y saber cómo acceder a cada dato?

Comment: @A. Cedano acabo de añadir una captura con el contenido analizado...

Comment: Pon el texto en vez de la imagen, si es posible identado para poder analizarlo mejor. Pon esto: `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($_FILES['file_array']); echo "</pre>";`, copia el resultado y pégalo en la pregunta tal cual (el texto).

Comment: @A. Cedano si escribo los echos así con las etiquetas, me manda un error de sintaxis.

Comment: `$name_array = echo'<pre>';  var_dump($_FILES['file_array']); echo'<pre>'; ['name'];`

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a poner la posición 0 en el array tal que así

```
$tmp_name_array[0]
```

Tienes que sacar lo que se encuentra dentro del Array

Comment: ya no me muestra el error del array pero La Ruta se esta guardando de la siguiente manera:       "C:wamp64 mpphpB115.tmp"     y no con el nombre de la imagen en la carpeta "imagenes"  Algo estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: @MarianaKiabeth Si estás usando NetBeans te recomiendo que uses el xDebug, de esa formas podrás ver que se almacena en cada variable y podrás seguir el flujo de tu código

Comment: estoy en editor de código sublime text 2.